# Estruturação Semântica em HTML5, Como Usar?

Tags: html5, semântica, prototipação

## Contexto

Estava fazendo um protótipo de template para um site, e me deparei com uma dúvida em relação a tag `<aside>`.

Abaixo vai um exemplo para explicar a divisão semântica.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Explicando as tags

> Tag **Header**
>
> > A tag header vai conter um logotipo no lado esquerdo, no centro um texto em `<h1>` e no lado esquerdo 4 símbolos que representam sites externos, como facebook ou linkedin.

---

> Tag **Nav**
>
> > Aqui vai constar o menu de navegação, abrangendo tag de tabela como `<li>` e `<ul>` com imagem representando cada elemento junto com tag.

---

> Tag **Main**
>
> > Conteúdo principal abrangerá 2 seções com elementos de texto e imagem, sendo mais específico, a seção da esquerda conterá apenas texto e a seção ao lado conterá a imagem ou algum elemento animado.

---

> Tag **footer**
>
> > Conterá apenas a data de criação e o copyright.

#### Dúvida 1

Quando devemos usar a tag `<aside>` ?

#### Dúvida 2

Essa tag se aplica no protótipo acima?

#### Dúvida 3

Alguém poderia informar se o protótipo acima está semanticamente correto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, a estrutura está correta. `<nav>` fora do `<main>`. Tudo bem divido, na minha opinião não há o que retocar.

Você poderá usar `<aside>` para incluir algum texto de destaque relacionado ao conteúdo em questão, bem como criar um submenu com links relacionados ao mesmo conteúdo.

Por exemplo, em um `<article>` sobre um determinado carro, você pode criar `<aside>` para chamar a atenção sobre alguma informação importante:

```
<article>
    O carro etc e tal foi fabricado em etc etc no país etc no período de 1970 a 1980 e teve versões etc etc...
    <aside>
        Foram fabricados apenas 100 unidades deste veículo.
    </aside>
    <aside>
        <h3>Versões:</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">1970</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1975</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1980</a></li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</article>
```

O `<aside>` funciona basicamente como aquelas caixas de destaque comumente visto em livros, revistas e jornais, algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas o `<aside>` também pode ser inserido numa `<section>` com o mesmo propósito, um texto em destaque com uma informação relevante ao conteúdo relacionado na `<section>`.

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta, esclareceu bastante =)